# angular 5 form with form builder

Tags: forms, angular5

I am trying to implement a form in Angular5. But there occurs a error in the console which states 'formGroup needs to have an instance of FormGroup'
This is the HTML code:

```
<form [formGroup]="userInfo" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
 <div class="input-section">
  <div class="form-group filled-form">
   <label for="businessName">What positions are you hiring for?</label>
   <input class="form-control myInputStyle" type="text" id="enterEmail" 
   formControlName="businessname" required>
   <div [hidden]="userInfo.controls['businessname'].valid || 
   userInfo.controls['businessname'].pristine" class="inline-error">
   Please enter a Business name!
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Here is the ts code :

```
export class HwaPreviewComponent implements OnInit {
public userInfo:FormGroup;
constructor(private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
}

onSubmit() {
if (this.userInfo.valid) {
  console.log("Form Submitted!");
}
}
```

Comment: Include this line in app.module.ts import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule }from '@angular/forms'; and include the Module  under Imports

Comment: that has already been added

Comment: userInfo should be instance of FormGroup, you have undefined

Comment: public userInfo:FormGroup; - adding this in the .ts file helped

Answer (score 0):

public userInfo:FormGroup; - adding this in the .ts file helped